# How to use grep "--help" command?

Tags: grep

This is the homework question: Write a command that ouputs a single line that tells what the `-c` option does in grep?
The hint is to use `grep --help`. The example for `-V` output is -V, --version display version information and exit.

I have tried to use `grep --help -V`. This does not work. Can someone show me an example.

The man page does not have an example. It just tells me that --help is supposed to output help on specific options.

Comment: If you execute `grep --help` or `man grep` you will get a documentation of how `grep` works and what options it takes. You are probably supposed to extract part of this help by using another `grep` call to do so. Read the output of `grep --help` or `man grep` to figure out how.

Comment: usage: grep [-abcDEFGHhIiJLlmnOoqRSsUVvwxZ] [-A num] [-B num] [-C[num]]
 [-e pattern] [-f file] [--binary-files=value] [--color=when]
 [--context[=num]] [--directories=action] [--label] [--line-buffered]
 [--null] [pattern] [file ...]

Comment: @uneven_mark grep --help gives me the output above. I tried to extract -V but there is really nothing there.

Comment: Is that all you get from `grep --help`? Then it is going to be harder than your instructor probably intended. This is not the output of GNU grep, that is usually used on linux systems. What OS and distribution are you on?

Comment: @uneven_mark I'm using a mac, OSMojav

Comment: Your instructor seems to assume that you are using Linux. Try to clear that up with them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199086/discussion-between-uneven-mark-and-daniel-li).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This isn't really an answer, but it's much too big to present properly as a comment.]

The `--help` option prints different things under different versions of grep.  On the first system I tried it (MacOS), it printed

```
usage: grep [-abcDEFGHhIiJLlmnOoqRSsUVvwxZ] [-A num] [-B num] [-C[num]]
    [-e pattern] [-f file] [--binary-files=value] [--color=when]
    [--context[=num]] [--directories=action] [--label] [--line-buffered]
    [--null] [pattern] [file ...]
```

It sounds like this is more or less what the OP's version of `grep` printed, and it's indeed hard to see how to process this to get help on just the `-c` option.

However, under the second system I tried it on, I got this:

```
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Search for PATTERN in each FILE or standard input.
PATTERN is, by default, a basic regular expression (BRE).
Example: grep -i 'hello world' menu.h main.c

Regexp selection and interpretation:
  -E, --extended-regexp     PATTERN is an extended regular expression (ERE)
  -F, --fixed-strings       PATTERN is a set of newline-separated fixed strings
  -G, --basic-regexp        PATTERN is a basic regular expression (BRE)
  -P, --perl-regexp         PATTERN is a Perl regular expression
  -e, --regexp=PATTERN      use PATTERN for matching
  -f, --file=FILE           obtain PATTERN from FILE
  -i, --ignore-case         ignore case distinctions
  -w, --word-regexp         force PATTERN to match only whole words
  -x, --line-regexp         force PATTERN to match only whole lines
  -z, --null-data           a data line ends in 0 byte, not newline

Miscellaneous:
  -s, --no-messages         suppress error messages
  -v, --invert-match        select non-matching lines
  -V, --version             display version information and exit
      --help                display this help text and exit

Output control:
  -m, --max-count=NUM       stop after NUM matches
  -b, --byte-offset         print the byte offset with output lines
  -n, --line-number         print line number with output lines
      --line-buffered       flush output on every line
  -H, --with-filename       print the file name for each match
  -h, --no-filename         suppress the file name prefix on output
      --label=LABEL         use LABEL as the standard input file name prefix
  -o, --only-matching       show only the part of a line matching PATTERN
  -q, --quiet, --silent     suppress all normal output
      --binary-files=TYPE   assume that binary files are TYPE;
                            TYPE is 'binary', 'text', or 'without-match'
  -a, --text                equivalent to --binary-files=text
  -I                        equivalent to --binary-files=without-match
  -d, --directories=ACTION  how to handle directories;
                            ACTION is 'read', 'recurse', or 'skip'
  -D, --devices=ACTION      how to handle devices, FIFOs and sockets;
                            ACTION is 'read' or 'skip'
  -r, --recursive           like --directories=recurse
  -R, --dereference-recursive
                            likewise, but follow all symlinks
      --include=FILE_PATTERN
                            search only files that match FILE_PATTERN
      --exclude=FILE_PATTERN
                            skip files and directories matching FILE_PATTERN
      --exclude-from=FILE   skip files matching any file pattern from FILE
      --exclude-dir=PATTERN directories that match PATTERN will be skipped.
  -L, --files-without-match print only names of FILEs containing no match
  -l, --files-with-matches  print only names of FILEs containing matches
  -c, --count               print only a count of matching lines per FILE
  -T, --initial-tab         make tabs line up (if needed)
  -Z, --null                print 0 byte after FILE name

Context control:
  -B, --before-context=NUM  print NUM lines of leading context
  -A, --after-context=NUM   print NUM lines of trailing context
  -C, --context=NUM         print NUM lines of output context
  -NUM                      same as --context=NUM
      --group-separator=SEP use SEP as a group separator
      --no-group-separator  use empty string as a group separator
      --color[=WHEN],
      --colour[=WHEN]       use markers to highlight the matching strings;
                            WHEN is 'always', 'never', or 'auto'
  -U, --binary              do not strip CR characters at EOL (MSDOS/Windows)
  -u, --unix-byte-offsets   report offsets as if CRs were not there
                            (MSDOS/Windows)

'egrep' means 'grep -E'.  'fgrep' means 'grep -F'.
Direct invocation as either 'egrep' or 'fgrep' is deprecated.
When FILE is -, read standard input.  With no FILE, read . if a command-line
-r is given, - otherwise.  If fewer than two FILEs are given, assume -h.
Exit status is 0 if any line is selected, 1 otherwise;
if any error occurs and -q is not given, the exit status is 2.

Report bugs to: bug-grep@gnu.org
GNU Grep home page: <http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/>
General help using GNU software: <http://www.gnu.org/gethelp/>
```

That looks much more promising.  Now we just need to figure out some way of extracting the single line:

```
  -c, --count               print only a count of matching lines per FILE
```

Bottom line: cute exercise, but inadvertently doomed to failure if you happen to be using MacOS or some other BSD-derived system.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
grep --help | grep c,
```

Comment: @DanielLi See my comment to your question. You seem to be running a different OS  / distribution than your instructor anticipated.

Comment: For v you just write grep --help | grep V,

Answer (score 0):

```
$ grep --help | grep -E "^\s+\-c"
```

Replace `-c` with whatever other option you're interested in.

Comment: Nevermind, after re-reading the message from the OP and the nature of the output of *their* `grep --help` output, I'm left struggling with the question "tells what the -c option does in grep?"    If that's all the output is, there is nothing there.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep --help | grep \\\\-c
```

Worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
man grep|grep Sup.*invert
```

Suppress normal output; instead print a count of matching lines for each input file.  With the -v, --invert-match option (see above), count non-matching lines.

Add B2 for read the two lines before... B1 for just show the -c!

```
  man grep|grep Sup.*invert -B1

   -c, --count
          Suppress normal output; instead print a count of matching lines for each input file.  With the -v, --invert-match option (see above), count non-matching lines.
```